# Ошибка при импорте telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

```
import time
import sqlite3
import requests
import json
import telebot
from telebot import types
API= '6983752287:AAH2A0BmREHcZQkAC3_P5g_xZu7oBaZeEok'  
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API) 


name = None

Ошбка: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Саша Стефанюк\Desktop\My TeleBots\MyfirstBot\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import telebot
  File "C:\Users\Саша Стефанюк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from telebot import types
  File "C:\Users\Саша Стефанюк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\types.py", line 6, in <module>
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'telebot' has no attribute 'TeleBot' (most likely due to a circular import). Did you mean: 'telebot'?
```